# How to remove a source when an error occurs in a zip operator in RxJava2?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have some sensor inputs from various devices wrapped in Observables.
I want to take the mean value of these sensor values, so a Zip operator seems appropriate. The issue now is that, when connection fails with one of the devices, I do not want the entire thing to just break. Standard behaviour is that if a source gives an error, all sources will terminate as well as the observable from the zip operator itself.
There are two problems with this standard behaviour:
1) When a source gives an error, the other sources will terminate, IE lose connection. The defer operator has to then reastablish this connection which takes some time. I want to transition seamlessly when a device gets removed.
2) Doing .onErrorResumeNext() on the failed source is not an option as this needs a source again. Doing Observable.just(0).repeat() is not acceptable as it is not clean to make special exceptions for 0 values when taking the mean of values.

The behaviour I want to achieve is to seamlessly just stop listening to the observable that gives an error and just go on with the ones that do still work.
Any one got any idea's on how to do this?

EDIT:
I have managed to keep the system working but not in the way I want. It is illustrated with the following code segment:

```
public FusedHeartRateSensor(HeartRateSensor... devices) {
    super("FusedHeartRateSensor", IoTType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_SENSOR, new FusedConnector(), devices);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Observable.fromIterable(fusedDevices)
            .flatMap(hrs -> hrs.monitorConnection())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(
                    state -> {
                        //Als iets verandert met de staat van de geconnecteerde toestellen moet
                        //de deviceChangeObservable op de hoogte gebracht worden
                        refreshConnectedDevices();
                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
            );
}

private void refreshConnectedDevices() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Refreshing enabled fused devices");
    List<HeartRateSensor> devices = fusedDevices.stream()
            .filter(Connectable::isConnected)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    deviceChangeObservable.onNext(devices);
}

private Observable<Integer> getMeanObservable(List<Observable<List<Integer>>> observables) {
    System.out.println();
    return Observable.zip(observables, objects -> getMean(Arrays.stream(objects).map(o -> (List<Integer>) o).filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()).map(this::getMean).collect(Collectors.toList())));
}
```

And a bit further when requested to monitor...

```
@Override
public Observable<Integer> monitorHeartRate() {
    ReplaySubject<Integer> resultObservable = ReplaySubject.create();
    CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    deviceChangeObservable.subscribe(
                    sensors -> {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Switched to new sources");
                        getMeanObservable(sensors.stream()
                                .map(s -> s.monitorHeartRate()
                                        .buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                .subscribe(
                                        t -> {
                                            resultObservable.onNext(t);
                                            System.out.println();
                                        },
                                        throwable -> {
                                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                                            System.out.println();

                                        }
                                );
                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println();
                    }
            );

    return resultObservable;
}
```

The problem with this is that, when a sensor fails in the zip operator, all of the other observables in the zip stop. My current solution is to retry the connection and set up a new zip observable only with the observables of devices that are still connected. The problem is that this is not seamless. I also tried this with defer and retry but this has the same result as the code above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have, showing how you read the values and proceed them in the `zip` operator. Provide example data how the observables or the `zip` operator should deal with the error from one device. Can/should the error device "come back" somehow and provide data for your `zip` operation again? Is caching the value with a behaviour subject an option?

Comment: Done, thank you for the comment.